# AngularJS - Filter results on date and string

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, you can filter results as follows:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="qcCtrl.searchTerm" placeholder="search" />

<tr ng-repeat="row in qcCtrl.data | filter: qcCtrl.searchTerm">
    <td>{{row.dateField | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td>{{row.textField}}</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine if the user enters text into the search box, but if they enter a date, no matches are found.

How do I create a filter that matches both on text and by date?

I have had a go at creating custom date filter function in my controller (below), but then this only works with dates, I want something that works with text and dates.

```
ctrl.filterDate = function (item) {

    var dateFilter = $filter('date');
    var formattedDateString = dateFilter(item.FifoDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

    return ctrl.searchTerm == null || ~formattedDateString.indexOf(ctrl.searchTerm);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I simply created another property on my object that contains the formatted date, the existing filter then worked:

```
angular.forEach(ctrl.data, function(value, index) {

value.FifoDate = new Date(parseInt(value.FifoDate.substr(6)));
value.searchFifoDate = $filter('date')(value.FifoDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I think there is no difference between filtering like this and filtering using date converted as a string! it will make your life simpler, if you want to filter a date, then use a datepicker instead!